# How to run a Vaadin 14 application with Spring Boot from jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, vaadin14

I have created a spring-boot and Vaadin application. I want to run it in production. Therefore I want to start it with

```
java -jar AppName.jar
```

But this gives the follwoing error, when i connect with a browser:

```
2021-08-24 14:38:32.404 ERROR 11476 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet.init() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine mode of operation. To use npm mode, ensure 'flow-build-info.json' exists on the classpath. With Maven, this is handled by the 'prepare-frontend' goal. To use compatibility mode, add the 'flow-server-compatibility-mode' dependency. If using Vaadin with Spring Boot, instead set the property 'vaadin.compatibilityMode' to 'true' in 'application.properties'.
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.verifyMode(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:456) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
```

I have this setting in my application.properties:

```
vaadin.productionMode = true
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.acme.coyote</groupId>
    <artifactId>VaadinWorklist</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>VaadinWorklist</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Secret Escape</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.4.2</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-dialog-flow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
     <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
     </profiles>

</project>
```

How to run the prepare-frontend goal? The official Vaadin documentation sucks and the hint are not working or I am too dumb to use them.

Comment: Did you already check these instructions in the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/production/#enabling-the-production-mode?

Comment: It might be worth it to download a fresh starter project from https://start.vaadin.com and copy the needed production profile from there.

Comment: yes when i insert this into the pom.xml i get and error: Invalid element name: executions

Comment: Could you try adding a production profile similar to this one: https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-spring/blob/30dc2d648d18de40db8f2aa56e1b2ce96e70f0fd/pom.xml#L185

Comment: I have copied the profiles part into my pom.xml, but maven does not get the plugin: No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\ACME\coyote\.m2\rep....

Comment: I have updated the pom.xml in the question. I was missing the plugin, Now it works. Thank you Tarek Oraby for your help.

Comment: I thought it was working until i opened the project in chrome :( This is crap! There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers.

Comment: How do you create the production build? Using `mvn clean package -Pproduction`?

Comment: mvn clean && mvn package -Pproduction && mvn spring-boot:run -Pproduction

Comment: Do you see a message in the logs that says "Vaadin is running in production mode"?

Comment: You might want to try upgrading the vaadin.version to 14.6.8 and the  spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.4.5 to see if that helps.

Comment: I did this already and yes i see at the startup: Vaadin is running in production mode

Comment: That's strange. I cannot spot any important difference between your pom.xml and that of the skeleton (https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-spring/tree/v14). And the latter works fine in production mode.

Comment: One more thing to try is the so-called "Vaadin Dance" described here: https://mvysny.github.io/Vaadin-troubleshooting/

Comment: I will check that, but i always thought with Vaadin, one does not need to know about the stupid Javascript. Thanks a lot. If i can not fix it, i will return to an older version of the framwork.

Comment: I dont know why. But it does work now. I am on a different machine. But i cannot tell what i changed that it worked. A good hint was to start it with this commands: mvn clean && mvn package -Pproduction && mvn spring-boot:run -Pproduction